# Implication of commutation relation of total momentum with a field operator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, momentum, commutator

If we have a free scalar field theory, and if I expand the field $\phi$ in terms of $a_p$ and $a_p^\dagger$, and by observing how $P^i$ acts on $a_p$ and $a_p^\dagger$, I can do a calculation to show that

$$\phi(\vec x,t)=e^{-iP^ix^i}\phi(\vec 0,t)e^{iP^ix^i}$$

In fact, a similar caluculation is done in ch. 2 in Peskin to relate $\phi(\vec x,t)$ and $\phi(\vec x,0)$ using the Hamiltonian.

Moreover, I noticed that, since for the free theory $P^i\equiv\int T^{0i}\mathrm{d}^3x=\int\pi\partial\phi\mathrm{d}^3x$, it follows from   the usual commutation relations for $\pi$ and $\phi$ that
$$[P^i,\phi]=-i\partial^i\phi.$$

So I'm wondering if we can use this relation to directly derive $\phi(\vec x,t)=e^{-iP^ix^i}\phi(\vec 0,t)e^{iP^ix^i}$ without having to expand the field in terms of $a_p$ and $a_p^\dagger$? If it's possible, how?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Sure.

Comment: @Qmechanic I got this. For $\delta \vec x$ small, I showed that $e^{-i\vec p\cdot\delta \vec x}\phi(0)e^{i\vec p\cdot\delta\vec x} = \phi(0) + \delta\vec x\cdot\nabla\phi(0)$. Is this statement sufficient to conclude the result, or is it necessary to expand all terms?